# Is there a way verify all Content files still exists?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that uses too many images and videos to set the Build Action as Resource, so I'm using Content instead. Is there a way that I can dynamically search those files the application was compiled with so that I can verify that all the files still exists on the computer at runtime? I'd rather not write up a file list that I have to constantly update when adding, removing, or renaming content files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to find so called loose content files in the runtime you should use Reflection and look for instances of *AssemblyAssociatedContentFileAttribute* attribute. This attribute is added automatically during build process of WPF application for every file with *Build Action = Content*.

To sum up, you can verify if your files exist on the target computer during the application startup in the following way:

```
public App()
{
    var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var attributes = a.GetCustomAttributes<AssemblyAssociatedContentFileAttribute>();
    foreach (var attr in attributes)
    {
        var path = attr.RelativeContentFilePath;
        //Verify if a given path exists
        ...
    }
}
```